# Pass ARView to Coordinator in Swift

Tags: swift, swiftui, arkit, coordinator-pattern

I'm trying to pass ARView from MakeUIView to makeCoordinator.
I need this to use ARView inside of `@objc func handleTap`.

```
struct ARViewContainer: UIViewRepresentable{
func makeUIView(context: Context) -> ARView {
        
        let myARView = ARView(frame: .zero)
        //...config and things….
        let tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: context.coordinator, action: #selector(context.coordinator.handleTap(_:)))
        myARView.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)
        return myARView
        
    }
func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
        Coordinator("whatshouldiusehere", self.$focusObject, self.$focusName)
    }
    class Coordinator: NSObject {
            private let view: ARView
        private var object: Binding<Entity?>
    private var objectname: Binding<String?>
        init(_ view: ARView, _ obj: Binding<Entity?>, _ objname: Binding<String?>) {
            self.objectname = objname
                self.object = obj
                self.view = view
                super.init()
            }
        @objc func handleTap(_ sender: UIGestureRecognizer? = nil) {
            guard let touchInView = sender?.location(in: view) else {
              return
            }
            guard let hitEntity = view.entity(at: touchInView) else {return}
            //doing something with object here, assigning to @Binding for example

        }
    }
}
```

I can't move `myARView = ARView(frame: .zero)` outside of `makeUIView`, because I'm using SwiftUI and it inits every time when variables changes.

But how I can pass it in any way?

Or is there any other option to access Binding with ARView same time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A coordinator is available via context, so you can inject it via property, like

```
struct ARViewContainer: UIViewRepresentable{
func makeUIView(context: Context) -> ARView {
        
        let myARView = ARView(frame: .zero)
        //...config and things….
        let tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: context.coordinator, action: #selector(context.coordinator.handleTap(_:)))
        myARView.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)
       
        context.coordinator.view = myARView     // << inject here !!

        return myARView
        
    }
func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
        Coordinator(self.$focusObject, self.$focusName)
    }
    class Coordinator: NSObject {
            var view: ARView?        // << optional initially

        private var object: Binding<Entity?>
        private var objectname: Binding<String?>
        
        init(_ obj: Binding<Entity?>, _ objname: Binding<String?>) {
                self.objectname = objname
                self.object = obj
                super.init()
            }

    // ... other code update accordingly
}
```